# HttpClient How to catch every response in one place

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms App connected with Web Api 2 Api and all requests and responses work with HttClient. This is my code:

class for all my requests and definiot of HttpClient

```
  public class DataStore : IDataStore<object>
    {
        HttpClient client;

        public DataStore()
        {
            client = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri($"{App.Uri}")
            };

        }
```

Example of one of my requests :

```
   public async Task<User> GetProfileSetup()
        {
            try
            {
                if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                {
                    string token = DependencyService.Get<ISharedFunctions>().GetAccessToken();

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

                    var response = await client.GetAsync(@"api/User/GetProfilSetup");
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string jsonMessage;
                        using (Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                        {
                            jsonMessage = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                        }
                        User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonMessage);


                        return user;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var m = response.Content.ToString();
                        return null;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                string error = ex.Message;
                return null;

            }
        }
```

My idea is to check every response(Response Status Code) in one place. I need this for throw Alert Errors , for refresh token etc. Is there a possible way to this ? I want to have control on every request/response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone have problem with this , just need to implement custom handler , who will inherit form DelegatingHandler. My code example:

```
  public class StatusCodeHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        public StatusCodeHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler) { }
        public GetStatusCode GetStatusCode = new GetStatusCode();
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return response;
                }
            else
            { 
                var status_code = (int)response.StatusCode;
                GetStatusCode.GetResponseCode(status_code);
            }
            return response;
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to xamarin, its a question of abstraction in OOP. You can and should abstract HttpClient and its methods to remove all the boilerplate.

Example - `GetAsync<T>(url)` will check for connectivity, forms request adds necessary headers, waits for response, checks response status, reads response and finally returns the deserialised response. That way, if you want to add caching layer it's easier. Basic OOP.

Abstracting your code:

```cs
public async Task<T> GetAsync(string url)
{
    try
    {
        if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            // throw custom exception?
            new NoNetworkException();
        }
        var token = DependencyService.Get<ISharedFunctions>().GetAccessToken();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // read response and throw for logging?
            new InvaidResponseException();// custom exceptions makes it easier for catching
        }
        using (Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            // there should be an async overload to read too
            var jsonMessage = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonMessage);
        }                
    }
    catch(NoNetworkException ex)
    {
        // handle
    }
    catch(InvaidResponseException ex)
    {
        // handle 
    }
}
```

Comment: I know its not xamarin , its basic for HttpClient, but i dont want in every async Task to  check response statuses  and duplicate the code. Just one place every response catch and make action

Comment: The above code should be inside DataStore class and a singleton object of DataStore should be used across all the http calls. If you want to single place to do ui actions like toasting... you should create method in BaseViewModel and call it on every catch of ViewModel

Comment: you have some example?

Comment: you mean GetAsync() call in every AsyncTask?